# Cisco VPN timeout issues

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I'm trying to use the native Cisco VPN client installed with Lion and it's been a terrible experience. The VPN times out between 15 and 45 minutes and I can't seem to fix it. I've followed guides for fixing this problem and it's gotten me nowhere. I copied the .conf files for each VPN that I have and disabled dead peer detection, changed proposal check to claim, and increased the lifetime time to 5 hours. I also changed my racoon.conf file to look in the directory where my custom .conf files are. I could stay connected all day when I used Ubuntu and I'd really like to have that ability back.

Is there a 3rd party client that I could use other than the Cisco one? I don't want to boot into 32-bit mode. Is there another fix that I missed?

Comment: Could you add what happenned at the time of failure? Please include the relevant parts of the useful logs for this trouble shooting (most probably `/var/log/system.log`).

Answer (score 1):

There is Cisco AnyConnect, which replaces the native VPN client. There is also a standalone Cisco VPN client for Mac.

[Link](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10884/products_tech_note09186a0080c08ec4.shtml)